# Can any one please tell me where I can find the latest python implementation of monero RingCT?

Tags: daemon, mymonero, ring-signatures, monero-community

Mininero is a python implementation of monero. But the git repository is three years old where the latest link does not have any content. Is there any other python implementation of monero where code for LSAG and ringCT is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented the Monero transaction code signing for the Trezor in python, the code is here:

https://github.com/ph4r05/monero-agent

And MLSAG in particular: https://github.com/ph4r05/monero-agent/blob/master/monero_glue/xmr/mlsag2.py

The python implementation also contains pure-python Bulletproofs implementation.

Comment: Thanks. In mlsag2.py, the parameter pk of the function gen_mlsag seems to be a matrix of Edpoints. Is it true? In particular, is there any test file calling gen_mlsag?

Comment: @trijia correct, `pubs` is the mixring matrix. I ported it mainly from the original C++ source so it should have similar interface.

It is called by transaction signer: `monero_glue/protocol/tsx_sign_builder.py`
There are tests for the whole transaction signing process in `monero_glue_test/test_agent_lite.py`

Comment: In `gen_mlsag`, `join` that is used in generating `m` is not working for `pk[0]` (a vector of Edpoints). It says that "expected str instance, EdPoint found".

Comment: `gen_mlsag` is old version of MLSAG, I've removed it now in the master. Better use `mlsag2.prove_rct_mg_simple` which is called by the `test_agent_lite.py`

Answer (score 0):

[Mininero](https://github.com/monero-project/mininero) has a python implementation of RingCT. I wouldn't rely on it being up-to-date with Monero's core implementation as if I recall correctly, it's purpose was originally a testbed of RingCT before it was implemented in Monero proper. Useful still for academic purposes nonetheless.